# Remove semicolon separated value from array and add as a new value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with semicolon separated value in an array. In the 10th index, there is 3 name [Leaf; Seed; Fruit] in 1 value.

Now, what I need that is removed seed and fruit from the 10th index and push them into an array as 41 and 42 indexes. Same thing in 37 and 39 indexes.

[image: array]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Help with what? With providing code?

Comment: How did you generate this array in the first place?

Comment: @catcon this is just an array named $plantPartNames from data base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop the array and explode on semicolon.
Then replace the value in the array with the first item of the exploded, and merge the rest with the main array.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $val){
    $temp = explode("; ", $val);
    $arr[$key] = $temp[0];
    $arr = array_merge($arr, array_slice($temp,1));
}

var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/epIY9

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php

// Array containing semi-colon space separated items
$plantPartNames = array(
    "a",
    "b",
    "c; d; e",
    "f",
    "g",
    "h; i; j",
    "k"
);

// Store additions
$additions = array();

// Loop through array
foreach ($plantPartNames as &$val) {
  // Check for semi-colon space
  if (strpos($val, "; ") === false) {
    continue;
  }
  // Found so split.
  $split = explode("; ", $val);
  // Shift the first item off and set to referenced variable
  $val = array_shift($split);
  // Add remaining to additions
  $additions = array_merge($additions, $split);
}

// Add any additions to array
$plantPartNames = array_merge($plantPartNames, $additions);

// Print
var_export($plantPartNames);

// Produces the following:
// array ( 0 => 'a', 1 => 'b', 2 => 'c', 3 => 'f', 4 => 'g', 5 => 'h', 6 => 'k', 7 => 'd', 8 => 'e', 9 => 'i', 10 => 'j', )

?>
```